# How to handle dynamic Id in selenium?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am working on automation and getting dynamic id each and every-time .Please find the sample code..

```html
<li class="list-group-items pingMessage clearfix" id="59580" data-reactid=".c.$0.0.$59580"></li>
<li class="list-group-items pingMessage clearfix" id="59581" data-reactid=".c.$0.0.$59580"><li>
<li class="list-group-items myMessage pingMessage clearfix bunch" id="59588" data-reactid=".e.$0.0.$59578"></li>
```

Every `<li>` item has a different id. I want to get an item's id value using `gettext` then store it in a variable and call in `xpath`.

I tried following code :

```
//Getting id of particular text 
WebElement Id=driver.findElement("By.xpath(//*[@class='list-group-items myMessage pingMessage clearfix bunch']").getText();
//My problem starts here i want to pass the stored id as id value how can i do it..

driver.findElement("By.id("+Id+")).click;
```

Comment: I have reworded some of your question, to improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

[`getText()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText--) is used to get the visible (i.e. not hidden by `CSS`) `innerText` of this element, including sub-elements, without any leading or trailing whitespace while you need here to get element `id` attribute, So you should try using [`getAttribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-) as below :-

```
//Storing the value of ID
WebElement Id = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".list-group-items.myMessage.pingMessage.clearfix.bunch")).getAttribute("id");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Saurabh.. After getting the id value how I can call it in my xpath value?

Comment: Do you want find same element by using found id??

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below xpath

```
//tagName[contains(@id='595')]
```